# Record user voice from web browser

Tags: java, php, python, google-chrome, web2py

I am simulating something similar to Google Chrome's voice recognition plugin.  I wish to record voice from web browser and send it to server for processing.  In short, I wish to do as described in [Accessing Google Speech API / Chrome 11](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/).  I have seen similar posts as this, but very few of them have been answered.  And also I wish to do it without flash. I know that it is possible, because chrome is doing it!  So how can we do it?  Any help in any language is appreciated and required!

Comment: *"So how can we do it?"* The answer is given in the 1st sentences of the linked document, namely *"..Google pushed version 11 of their Chrome browser into beta, and along with it, one really interesting new feature- support for the **HTML5 speech input API.**"*  Should I enter that as an answer?

Comment: Yes!! got it!Thank you very much @Andrew.You may enter this as answer!.And if you could recommend me some nice tutorial for that.I know many of them are there.But would appreciate if you could recommend some!

Comment: @Anthony,does web2py support this HTML5 speech input API?

Comment: Comment entered as answer. :)

Comment: First, I don't think you want the speech API -- that does speech recognition right in the browser and converts the speech to text. It would then send the converted text to the server, not the recorded audio. You might be more interested in [getUserMedia](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Anyway, web2py doesn't have any special support for these, but there should be no problem using them with web2py.

Comment: "It would then send the converted text to the server, not the recorded audio." I am not sure of that @Anthony.See http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/. BTW this cleared it:"there should be no problem using them with web2py".Thanks :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..how can we do it?"

The answer is provided in the linked document, namely:

> ..Google pushed version 11 of their Chrome browser into beta, and along with it, one really interesting new feature- support for the **HTML5 speech input API.**

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML 5 Speech API, but it is not supported by all the browsers yet. We may need to wait for some more time to get it supported by all the browsers.

Comment: Can u name some browsers which support them other than chrome?

Comment: I am not sure what all other browsers support this feature than chrome. We can test whether a browser enabled with this feature or not by following javascript code.                                  `if (document.createElement("input").webkitSpeech === undefined) {
 alert("Speech input is not supported in your browser.");
}`

Comment: Thanks +1 for ya! Let us find out some browsers supporting it and you can edit your answer to include those so that it helps others:-)